# Update time zone rules on LineageOS 18.1

Tags: lineageos, android-11, date-and-time, time-zones

I have a Xiaomi Mi 8 Lite on which I have installed LineageOS 18.1. The time zone rules changed in my country this year.

I've tried a lot of things to fix it; like taking the `tzdata` and `tz-version` files from a different device and putting them in `/system/usr/share/zoneinfo` but nothing worked.

How can this be fixed?